# Asking questions / Giving advice which may break the law?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, legal

So a user asks:

[How do I minimize the chances of TSA agents confisticating liquids larger than 3 ounces?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7916/101)

on Travel.SE.

Now, if the TSA rules are legally binding, aren't they essentially asking about breaking the law? And if so, should we close it, and under what category?

*Aside: Does anyone know if the TSA rules on liquids are legally binding?*

**edit** - ignoring any misgivings you have about the TSA, please  ;)

**FURTHER EDIT - note above - this is not just about the TSA, it's what to do when someone asks about breaking the law on SE sites.**

Comment: TSA is not a legit outfit.

Comment: that's not really the question...

Comment: Can't break a law if there isn't a law to break

Comment: yet they have pages like this: http://www.tsa.gov/research/laws/regs/editorial_multi_image_with_table_0205.shtm which seem to imply they're a branch of the government with laws...

Comment: The TSA likes to imply a lot of things

Comment: @random So you're saying that the [TSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_Security_Administration) is not a branch of the government of the USA, which means you're implying the [DHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Homeland_Security) is also not a part of the USA government.

Comment: random♦ is random, guys.  I wouldn't read too much into what he says =)

Comment: Per [this post](http://blog.tsa.gov/2008/01/liquids.html?showComment=1201812660000#c2892858942693320438) it sounds like the TSA is basically abusing the regs upon which they base the liquids rule

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17509/how-to-handle-questions-that-may-have-legal-concerns

Comment: @MarkMayo, the TSA has regulations, not laws. There are no crimes that can be committed purely by carrying liquids through security.

Comment: Do you have evidence for this? They even head up their page as "Laws" - http://www.tsa.gov/research/laws/law_regulation_rule_0010.shtm

Comment: @MarkMayo, NO ANGENCY for the US gov can pass ANY laws. All any agency (be it the FDIC, SEC, TSA, etc) can do is make regulations. These regulations are limited in scope to the areas that they regulate. The right to pass laws is reserved to the legislative branch (of the states or federal government).

Comment: @MarkMayo, the laws that they are referring to on that page are the laws that congress wrote that give them their authority.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Now, if the TSA rules are legally binding, aren't they essentially asking about breaking the law?

Well, maybe. But if *you're* unsure as to whether or not those rules are legally-binding, much less whether or not they're actually asking how to *break* them, then chances are they're in the same boat. Closing it doesn't really accomplish anything here, apart from sending someone with a (constructive, probably on-topic) question away empty handed.

If it's illegal, then that's an answer. There should be plenty of sources that can be referenced in this case.

If it's just a bad idea, then an answer explaining why could potentially save someone a *lot* of headaches.

If it's legitimately possible (even if only in specific circumstances) then that would be very nice to know as well... And again, someone should be able to cite official sources here.

**When in doubt, err on the side of *helping people*,** not shutting them down just because their question makes you uncomfortable. And remember, ["don't do it" *is* a valid answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) - as long as you explain *why.*

Note that there are plenty of reasons why your community may decide that they don't want to be involved in answering questions on certain topics, including concerns about projecting an *image* of lawlessness. This is a decision that should be made by your constituents on your meta.

Note also that some types of content are prohibited by our [Content Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) and [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) - generally, you shouldn't get too hung up on these, but be aware that we (Stack Exchange Inc.) may be required to remove posts that violate them.

Comment: they've not been shut down yet - and certainly we always explain closures.  Our policy with borderline cases has been to let the community decide, but now I was starting to wonder...

Comment: @Mark: Yeah... My best advice is not to get paranoid about this. You're not a lawyer, and you can't possibly be aware of all the different laws that might apply to a given situation worldwide. If there's a reasonable chance that someone is honestly looking for a solution to a real problem they're facing, if it's on-topic, and if it's constructively-asked... Let it be.